# Relation between transfer function and resolvent set

Tags: operator-theory, spectral-theory, nonlinear-system, semigroup-of-operators

I am studying an infinite dimensional system in the form 
$$
\begin{array}{l} 
 \dot{x}= Ax+Bu, \\
y=Cx,
\end{array}
$$
where  $A$ is the generator of a analytic semigroup and $B$ and $C$ are bounded operators. 
My question is, what is the relation between the domain transfer function
$
G(s)=C(Is-A)^{-1}B
$
and the resolvent set $\rho(A)$ ?

Thanks for the time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have
$$G(s)=CR(s,A)B,$$
where $R(s,A)$ is the resolvent of the operator $A$. Since $B$ and $C$ are bounded, the resolvent set $\rho(A)$ is the domain of definition of $G(s)$.